# Redirect 301 for urls with extension to none but under few directories tree level

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I found this solution to redirect urls from `www.domain.com/example.php` to `www.domain.com/example` successfully but I cannot do the same when are few subdirs present, like with: `domain.com/dir1/di2/dir3/example.php` to `domain.com/dir1/di2/dir3/example`

How should this rule be modded in order to make the previous redirection work?

```
RewriteRule (.*).php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*).html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is my .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /misc/404.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule (.*).php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*).html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
#RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Those rules work fine for redirecting `/dir1/di2/dir3/example.php` to `/dir1/di2/dir3/example` for me.

Comment: `http://demo.domain.com/en/index.php` is taking me to `http://demo.domain.com/index`, I'll update the post to put my current rules.

Comment: It is inside the directory that has the final example.php file, do you want me to place it also on public_html/ ?

Comment: You mean it's in `dir3`? (or in your second example, `en`?

Comment: `http://demo.domain.com/en/index.php` is taking me to `http://demo.domain.com/index` and it should take me to `http://demo.domain.com/en/index`

Comment: Yes, the .htaccess is in /en/ directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `http://demo.domain.com/en/index.php` is taking me to `http://demo.domain.com/index` and it should take me to `http://demo.domain.com/en/index`
>
> the .htaccess is in /en/ directory

You need to add a:

```
RewriteBase /en/
```

right below `RewriteEngine on`.

You also may need to add a `/en/` to the redirect rules and conditions:

```
RewriteRule (.*).php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*).html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Needs to be:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule (.*).php$ /en/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule (.*).html$ /en/$1 [R=301,L]
```